# Retrieve and replace email address using preg_match & preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, email-validation

I want to retrieve email address from an article when the article is submitted and replace the email address with `*`.

I am using preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches). Does not work throws an error.

$pattern looks like this

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$
```

I want retrieve the email address and replace it * in the article.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, whatever this --> `↪` funny little character is won't be helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex is:

```
#^[^\.][\w-\.]{1,64}[^\.]@([\w-\.]*)(\.\w{2,6})$#i
```

Comment: This is ridiculously over simplified. [Read this](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php).

Comment: can you show me the example email where this regexp wouldn't work? :)

Comment: .local-starts-with-dot@sld.com and local-starts-with-dot.@sld.com - done!

Comment: http://codepad.org/7Cizzg1H - First array should contain all addresses, second should be empty. Have fun ;)

Comment: if you need hard email address validation you can simply use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to validate email after regexp check. You should keep in mind that regexp check takes a lot of system resources and if your regexp is rather complex and you have lots of concurent connections your server would just Stop sometimes :)